# When do called the appdelegate's managedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What is the best way to access my managedObjectContext.  According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822988/app-failed-to-resume-in-time-and-hangs) I should not be doing so in finishedLoad: method.

Is it good practice to access my managedObjectContext in this way from ANY of my app's models:

(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]).managedObjectContext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can access the context from any method of any class in your app, and the syntax you show should work fine -- if you add another opening paren at the beginning.

In the post you mention, I don't think Mr. Zarra is advising against *any* access of the context from applicationDidFinishLaunching. He's cautioning you not to use the context at this point to process changes across an entire database or to fetch large amounts of data. If you need to access a managed object or two in order to guide the display of your UI from within applicationDidFinishLaunching, that should be all right.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Wienke. There's nothing wrong with accessing your Core Data stack in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, as long as you don't start *processing* data within that method. You should load a new view controller, set its managed object context, and start the process asynchronously after that view loads.

I'm not clear from your question whether you're trying to access the managed object context inside your app delegate or if you're trying to access it from a different class. If you're accessing it from a different class, your proposed code creates a tight coupling that reduces reusability of your code. A better practice would be to set a property when you instantiate the class.
When you code your view controller classes, make sure you set up a synthesized property for the view controller:

```
// CustomViewControllerClass.h
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

// CustomViewControllerClass.m
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
```

When you load your view controller in your app delegate, pass the app delegate's managed object context to the view controller:

```
// MyAppDelegate.m (inside application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)
        CustomViewController *controller = (CustomViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
        controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

This way, if you have a Core Data stack that is not set up in your app delegate, your custom class can easily accept the managed object context from whatever class instantiates it.

Comment: My first view controller needs certain data placed an retreived from the db though.  thats the prob

Comment: You can still accomplish that. Your first view controller can fetch what it wants in viewDidLoad. That way your UI loads and you can avoid the problem you seek to avoid. Better yet, use gcd to load your data and update the UI from a method called in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer to this post:

[Passing managedObjectContext - is this efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501764/passing-managedobjectcontext-is-this-efficient/7514926#7514926)

Basically, I create a singleton using Matt Gallagher's macro, and access that anywhere like this:

```
[[MyPersistentStoreController sharedMyPersistentStoreController] managedObjectContext]];
```

You'll find all the details and the link to Matt's post in the link above.