# Core Data - Runtime Crash when creating NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, runtime-error, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using a TableViewController class that is much like the one that is created when you start a new Master-Detail Application project in Xcode. As such, I'm using the same code that is pre-populated in the TableViewController class for my own use. However, I'm getting a runtime crash and I'm not sure why. I use this exact code in another class of my app and it works perfectly.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Binder" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    //NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
    //NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    //[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".

//This is where it crashes
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
//End crash
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I'm not sure what other code snippets to include here. Output doesn't tell me anything when the crash happens, and Xcode jumps to this part of the Main Thread:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__kill:
0x972893b0:  movl   $786469, %eax
0x972893b5:  calll  0x9728b4c2                ; _sysenter_trap
0x972893ba:  jae    0x972893ca                ; __kill + 26 //This is highlighted
0x972893bc:  calll  0x972893c1                ; __kill + 17
0x972893c1:  popl   %edx
0x972893c2:  movl   27739(%edx), %edx
0x972893c8:  jmpl   *%edx
0x972893ca:  ret    
0x972893cb:  nop
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: From what do you take that this is the point where the crash happens? Did you set an Exception Breakpoint? If yes, then you may have to continue execution one or twice before the exception gets visible in the debug console. How does your call stack look like and what is your error message in the debug console?

Comment: Yes, I set an Exception Breakpoint. The breakpoint is set for "On Catch", though it stops at the same spot when I set it to "On Throw". However, when the Exception Breakpoint happens, I do continue execution, and that's when it then stops at the second bit of code I posted. The only thing that is in the Debug Console is `(lldb) `

Comment: What happens if you are setting cache to `nil`?

Comment: @Mundi I get the same "error". I put that in quotes because I don't actually get an error, it just crashes... I'm going to try putting my model in the Apple generated code and see what happens with that

Comment: Did you try setting up the NSFetchedResultsController with using the NSSortDescriptor "enabled"? Normally you have to use a sort descriptor when using an NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: @flashfabrixx That was it! I was unaware that a sort descriptor was required when using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. When I uncommented those three lines, it worked perfectly. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to answer your own question so that other users can see the answer as well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @flashfabrixx, the problem was that I was not using a sort descriptor and they are required when using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. Once I added the sort descriptor back in, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only non-standard thing you are doing is that you are using a managed object context from the app delegate. This is really not recommended, for many good reasons.

Try changing this by adding a context property to your master controller and using that context to create your fetched results controller (both for getting a reference to the entity and for the FRC creation).

Finally, ensure your model indeed contains a valid `Binder` entity.

Comment: The standard way is setting a local managed object context as a copy of the app delegate ones. The standard way is having one context only anyway. So unless you hassle with two or more of them and change the one in the app delegate, there should not be a problem at all. What are the good reasons for not using the reference from app delegate directly?

Comment: Well, one is that you are calling a getter from your app delegate each time is less efficient. Another one is that this might return `nil` as seems to be the case here. The "many good reasons" are beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Ah, right, calling a getter from app delegate is of course less efficient than calling a getter from self. Sorry for having asked. However, if the MOC in app delegate is really nil then there is a problem far beyond the question whether this has a measureable influence on performance or not.

Comment: @Mundi I can say that it's not returning `nil`. However, even when I create a new MOC in here, the result is the same. I know that my model contains a valid `Binder` entity because I use this same code elsewhere to display other contents of the model.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker You are right in claiming that getting a pointer from self or a delegate has no measurable performance difference. Your polemics are quite amusing as well. I think it is more a question of program design and the MVC philosophy. See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7515156/427083).

Comment: @Mundi, I do agree upon the design and style thing. It is just hat Apple does it quite similar within the auto-generated sceleton code when you start an iPad app with core data from scratch. Whether it is polemical to ask for "may good reasons" that you have not further specified or not to give a better answer than "that is beyond the question" (which it is not), may the reader decide.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `nil` managed object context to `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:` will throw an exception. I'm surprised you're not seeing anything in the console log though.

Try `NSAssert()` to verify that your MOC, and the `Binder` entity, are both non-nil.

If the cache name in your `NSFetchedResultsController` has been used for another FRC, you'll see an error unless the two controllers' fetch requests are identical. Set a `nil` (or different) `cacheName:` and see if you get a different result.

Comment: My MOC is not `nil` when it gets passed to `initWithFetchRequest`. I even changed to `managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` so that I could see the memory address of the MOC to see that it is not `nil` I've never used `NSAssert()` before, but I think that I set it up correctly. I did `NSAssert(managedObjectContext != nil, @"No MOC");` and `NSAssert(entity != nil, @"No entity");` and it passed by both NSAsserts, so I guess that means neither is `nil`. Setting `nil` for `cacheName:` gives the same results.